# HTML and Javascript - Two input boxes, one button and an output box

Tags: javascript, html

The idea is to make a OTP(one time pad) encoder and later also a decoder. This is the implementation - two input boxes. One contains key and one a message. There is also a box which displays "OTPencrypt". If you click on the OTP button it does the function called initialize and displays the result in the output box. I don't know how to make the OTPencrypt button and output box "connected".
My code in HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="Input" value="Sisend">
</body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function initialaize() {
  var message = document.getElementById("Input").value;
  var key = document.getElementById("Key").value;
  var end_message = "";
  var chipertext = "";
  var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  var alphamap = new Map();
    for (i = 0; i < alphabet.lenght, i++) {
      alphamap.set(alphabet[i], i);
    }
    for (a = 0; i < key.lenght; i++) {
      var value_original = alphamap.get(message[a]) ;
      var value_key = alphamap.get(key[a]);
      var value = getByValue(alphamap, ((value_original + value_key) % 26));
      chipertext += value;
      }
      function getByValue(map, searchValue) {
        for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
          if (value === searchValue) {
            return key;
          }
        }
      }
      return chipertext;
    }
</script>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="Key" value="Key(kui vaja)">
</body>

<body>
  <button id="OTPencrypt">OTPencrypt</button>
</body>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="result" value=result readonly="true">
</body>
</html>
```

I want the result to display the initialaize result if OTPencrypt is pressed. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You must add an onClick event listener to the `#OTPencrypt` button, to set the textbox's value to the output of your function

Add the following to the JS code:

```
document.getElementById("OTPencrypt").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    document.getElementsByName("result")[0].value=initialaize()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to the button and tell it to run `initialize` when it's been clicked, this is how your code would look like..

run the snippet and see the results

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="Input" type="text" name="Input" value="sisend">
  <input id="Key" type="text" name="Key" value="kuiva">
  <button id="OTPencrypt">OTPencrypt</button>
  <input type="text" id="result" name="result" placeholder=result readonly="true">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('OTPencrypt').addEventListener('click', () => {
      document.getElementById('result').value = initialaize();
    });


    function initialaize() {
      var message = document.getElementById("Input").value;
      var key = document.getElementById("Key").value;
      var end_message = "";
      var chipertext = "";
      var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
      var alphamap = new Map();
      for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
        alphamap.set(alphabet[i], i);
      }
      for (var a = 0; a < key.length; a++) {
        var value_original = alphamap.get(message[a]);
        var value_key = alphamap.get(key[a]);
        var value = getByValue(alphamap, ((value_original + value_key) % 26));
        chipertext += value;
      }
      return chipertext;
    }

    function getByValue(map, searchValue) {
      for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
        if (value === searchValue) {
          return key;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Please Note that you need to twerk some of the logic in the function to cover every input possibility..

hope that helps.